# EF Core 2.0.0 and Redis.Core 1.0.3 don't work together

Tags: c#, redis, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I tried to setup a .net core console application which uses [`EF core 2.0.0`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer/2.0.0) and [`Redis.Core 1.0.3`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Redis.Core/1.0.3) (both are the current latest version).

Unfortunately if you try to put both into one application it won't even start. Even if you try to set a breakpoint right at the beginning or start debugging with `Step into` or `Step Over` doesn't help. All you get is this:
[image: The application is in break mode]

I think there happens some kind of type load exception or something similar. So far to reproduce the problem is quite easy with this project:

**Project File (`MyProject.csproj`)**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Redis.Core" Version="1.0.3" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

**Application (`Program.cs`)**

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Redis;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;

namespace MyApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var cache = new RedisCache(Options.Create(new RedisCacheOptions()));
        }
    }
}
```

Anybody an idea or solution?

Comment: As per this Git issue: https://github.com/aspnet/Caching/issues/348 Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Redis.Core is not an official Microsoft Package.  The recommendation is to remove the Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Redis.Core and install Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Redis which IS the official Microsoft Package

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that

- `Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Redis.RedisCache 1.0.3` depends on `Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions 1.0.3`
- `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 2.0.0` depends on `Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions 2.0.0`

If you look at the Output Window, you will get:

> `TypeLoadException`: Method `GetAsync` in type
>   `Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Redis.RedisCache` from assembly
>   'Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Redis, Version=1.0.3.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' does not have an implementation.

So: either wait until `RedisCache` gets updated to `2.0.0` or use `EntityFrameworkCore < 2.0.0`

Comment: The upgrade is available now
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Redis